# How we can insert data without using insert clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

How we can insert data without using insert clause ??

Comment: That's what `INSERT` clauses are for. Why do you want to use something else?

Comment: Is that a trick question? If so, one possible answer is `SELECT ... INTO` syntax.

Comment: Interviewer ask me this question
Is this is possible ??

Comment: A bit of context would have helped

Comment: Merge statement can do inserts. But there are issues with Merge and many avoid it.

Comment: You need provide more information like the the context, system, tools, limitations, etc.

Comment: Create table as select , Load data infile, select into, restore from backup, and whatever import options your ide has available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can :

- Right mouse button on the database -> Tasks -> Import Data...
- `SELECT * INTO FROM`
- Right mouse button on the table -> Edit Top 200 Rows -> copy the record from  another source or fill in the data yourself
- `OUTPUT DELETED. * INTO/ OUTPUT INSERTED. * INTO`
- `OPENROWSET`

And probably some other ways someone will find :)

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what you exactly want, but this can do:

````
INTO newtable
FROM oldtable
WHERE condition;

OR you can also do:

SELECT * INTO newtable FROM (
SELECT top 100 * FROM oldtable1
UNION All
SELECT top 100 * FROM oldtable2
UNION All
SELECT top 100 * 
FROM oldtable3
UNION All
SELECT top 100 * 
FROM oldtable4
) as tmp```
````